# If an atom is positively ionized, can is gain electrons if you emit photons at it?

Tags: photons, electrons, ionization-energy

I read somewhere that electrons and light are just electromagnetic radiation and are basically the same thing, does this mean that if you emit photons at an atom it will gain electrons?

Comment: Where did you read this? Electrons are not electromagnetic radiation, and they are definitely not the same thing.

Comment: Ray, you might find this helpful: http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-photon-and-vs-electron/

Answer (score 3):

No.

Photons and electrons are fundamentally different and you cannot convert one into the other. it is **incorrect** to state that 'electrons and light are just electromagnetic radiation'; only light is electromagnetic radiation. Photons can be emitted and absorbed, and their number is not conserved. Electron number, on the other hand, is conserved, so electrons cannot appear or disappear.

There is, however, one corner case to be aware of. Electrons can indeed be created as long as an anti-electron - a [positron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positron) - is created in the same process. (Electron number is then conserved because each positron counts as -1 electron.) This process is known as pair creation and requires a very high-energy photon, in the gamma-ray regime. The electron and positron are created with very high energy and are unlikely to be captured by an atomic ion.

Answer (score 1):

@Emilio Pisanty mentioned the process where "if you emit photons at an atom it will gain electrons": a photon creates an  electron-positron pair in the Coulomb field of the ion, the electron is captured by the atom, and the positron goes free. I just wanted to give a reference (it is theoretical, and I don't know if this process was observed experimentally: http://phys-merger.physik.unibas.ch/~aste/pairprod.pdf (Phys. Rev. A, vol. 50, #5 (1994), p. 3980). Part of abstract: "Calculations of the electron-positron pair production by a single photon in the Coulomb field of a nucleus with simultaneous capture of the electron into the $K$ shell are presented. Numerical results are given for some nuclear charges up to 92 and energies from threshold to 15 MeV."

Another thing. For what it's worth, in my article http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/480/art%253A10.1140%252Fepjc%252Fs10052-013-2371-4.pdf?auth66=1409005273_07ba932f8b56293b8de90c570f873db2&ext=.pdf (published in the Europen Physical Journal C), I show that both electromagnetic field and spinor field can be described by the same modified Maxwell equations for the (complex) 4-potential of the electromagnetic field only  (please see some important details there).